# Send intent from Chrome opens App in Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, ionic-framework, android-intent, capacitor

When I share a link from Chrome to my App, it doesn't open in the App's process but in Chrome itself.

[Intent opened in Chrome, not in App process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwFZp.jpg)

I have an Ionic 5 App with React and Capacitor as Bridge. My share target is configured as follows:

```
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
            android:name="de.mindlib.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/custom_url_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"  />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I would like to have the share target open in the App's process. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi CK_One, did you find a solution? I got the same issue. Is it a Chrome bug? 
I discovered 2 different behaviors. 
- When I tap on the menu button Share... and then I select my application, the App is open in Chrome. 
- However if I tap on the my App icon located on the right of the menu button Share …, my App is open normally.

Comment: I didn't find a solution yet. Maybe it is a chrome issue, because I observed this behaviour with different apps.